# Django Rest Framework: Change Serializer or Add Field Based on Authentication

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I have a viewset as follows:

```
class CardViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    Standard Viewset for listing cards
    """
    pagination_class = StandardCellSetPagination
    permission_classes = [AllowAny, IsAuthenticated]

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Card.objects.exclude(reply_to__isnull=False).order_by('-created')
        cards = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        serializer = CardCellSerializer(cards, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Card.objects.all()
        card = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = CardSerializer(card)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

My serializer for the CardSerializer is:

```
class CardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Card
```

How do I either

- Change the serializer for the retrieve method if the viewset has the permission `IsAuthenticated`?
  OR
- Add a field to the `CardSerializer` if viewset has `IsAuthenticated`?

Such that I can return `True / False` if a user has favorited the card via a `SerializerMethodField`

Comment: What are trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @Ivan If a user is authenticated I want the serializer to return if a user has favorited the card or not. This I was thinking of achieving via a `SerializerMethodField`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this:

```
def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
    queryset = Card.objects.all()
    card = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)

    # Same for list method
    if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated:
        serializer = AuthenticatedCardSerializer(card)
    else:
        serializer = CardSerializer(card)

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

`AuthenticatedCardSerializer` could then extend `CardSerializer` to include any fields visible to authenticated users.

Also if you decide to use same serialization behavior for `list` and `retrieve`, you could override `get_serializer_class` in your viewset instead:

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.request.user and self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        return AuthenticatedCardSerializer
    else:
        return CardSerializer
```

and leave everything else to the default `list`/`retrieve` implementations.

As an alternative, you could add the field in serializer's `__init__`. You can get the request from the `context` kwarg, do the same check and add any fields you need. I think though that it is needlessly more complicated than just having two serializers.